# Need to prove that $A_k=(-1)^k {n \choose k}$

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, factorial

> In the identity
>   $$
> \frac{n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)\ldots(x+n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{A_k}{x+k}},
> $$
>   prove that
>   $$
> A_k=(-1)^k {n \choose k}\text{ .}
> $$

How should I proceed with this problem? A push in the right direction or stating the prerequisites for this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: In the rhs do the lcm and look at the numerator.Substitute some particular value in the identity for x to get the coefficient of $A_{i}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we multiply both sides by $(x+k) $ and in the resulted equality, we replace $x $ by $-k $, we find

$$0+0+...+A_k+0+0+...0=$$
$\frac {n!}{-k (1-k)... (k-1-k) . (k+1-k)(k+2-k)... (n-k) }=$

$$\frac {n!}{((-1)^k.k!)((n-k)!}= $$

$$(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}=A_k$$

This technic is used in partial fractions decomposition.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further on how we're obtaining the zeroes in the right hand side?

Comment: for example, the first zero comes from \frac {A_0}{x}(x+k) $  and $x=-k $.

Comment: The second zero is from $\frac {A_1}{x+1}(x+k) $ and $x=-k $.

Comment: Oh now I understand. Thank you!